# How to make Pyramid in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a function which can take 5 and get me pyramid accordingly.

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

e.g

```
def pyramid(x):
....

pyramid(5) # it must print 5 lines with * to look like pyramid as above.
```

This is what I have tried but not getting pyramid as expected

```
rows = int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
for row in range(0, rows):
    for _ in range(0, row + 1):
      print('*', end=' ')
    print('')


# result was 

* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Hope it's clear.

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you share the code you've written and point out the part that isn't working that you're stuck on?

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
def pyramid(x):
    side = x
    middle = 1
    for i in range(x):
        line = ""
        for _ in range(side):
            line += "  "
        for _ in range(middle):
            line += " *  "
        for _ in range(side):
            line += "  "
        print(line)
        middle+=1
        side -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make like this:

```
def triangle(n):
 
    k = n - 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end=" ")
        k = k - 1
        for j in range(0, i+1):
     
            print("* ", end="")
        print("\r")
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe that each row `r` (1 to x) is indented by `x - r` spaces prior to `r` space separated stars.

Here is an iterative version:

```
def pyramid(x):
    for r in range(1, x + 1):
        print(' ' * (x - r) + ' '.join(['*'] * r))
```

and a recursive version:

```
def pyramid(x, indent=0):
    if x <= 0: return
    pyramid(x - 1, indent + 1)
    print(' ' * indent + ' '.join(['*'] * x))
```

Comment: can you please vote my question? so I can upvote all of you. right now I don't have enough points to upvote anyone